# How to access ModelAttribute value without path

Tags: java, jstl, modelattribute

I have a `@ModelAttribute` `someString` in my Controller. How can I access the value in my JSP? I tried this:

```
<form:input path=""/>
```

but it doesn't work

Please help.

Comment: Hum, what about `${someString}`?

Comment: actually, that should work. since all `path=` does is set the value for the field. rest is done automagically my `ModelAttribute` and the `Form`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to define it in the jsp form? Something like this..?

```
<form:form id="form" action="${formAction}" method="post" modelAttribute="someString" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```